# IOS 11 Update changed color of my nodes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

This post is regarding an app that I already have in the AppStore. Its not been updated for months now so I'm totally sure that the version in AppStore was working before the iOS 11.2 update. Here is the problem/bug:

In the app you can choose between different types of dice to roll in AR. You can select the regular dice with is white/grey with black dots. The dice node is a SCNBox with 6 images attached to its sides. These images looks like this: 
[image]

and I know that these are the images that gets added as the nodes materials:
[image]

But when I roll the dice it looks like this:
[image: Notice that the black dots appear]

THE DICE ARE RED!?!?! but somehow the black dots still appear

So the question I would like to ask you guys is this, do you know what might have caused this? Couldn't find anything in the iOS 11.2 release notes that should affect the dice in any way.

EDIT:

Tried setting material.diffuse.textureComponents = .red
[image]

The dice are now white, but the colors are wrong. The dots are not black anymore and the white/grey gradient is inverted.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the Asset Catalog compiler automatically converts the images to ones with a grayscale colour space. In this case setting [`.textureComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/2865880-texturecomponents?language=objc) to `SCNColorMaskRed` will solve the issue.

The idea is that the red colour channel will also be used for the green and blue colour channels, instead of having a value of `0.0`.

Comment: I tried setting .displacement.textureComponents = .red to all the materials but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: `displacement`? Your images are set on the `diffuse` material property.

Comment: sorry bout that this turned the dices white. Sort of inverted the colors so that the black dots now are white too. Ill add a image to the question